# How do I identify where the click of a UILabel came from?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uilabel

In my program, when the "newFrees" function is run, it should activate the ability to click on some labels. Depending on which label the user clicks, it should do something different. I've gotten to the point where I can make it run a function when one of the labels is pressed, but I don't know how to make that function identify which label called it. Is there a way I could identify the name of the label that called it?

```
func newFrees() -> Void {

    BM1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    BT2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
    let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
    BM1.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
    BT2.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
}
```

...

```
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap working")
}
```

// BM1 and BT2 are labels.

Also, is there a way to not have to use "let tap1' and "let tap2"? Whenever I just define it as "tap" and then add it to both BM1 and BT2, BT2 works, but not BM1.

Comment: start var names with small letter

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  if bm1 == sender.view {
     print("bm1 clicked")
  }
  else {
     print("bt2 clicked")
   }
}
```

You have to create a tap instance for each object , creating 1 and adding it to 2 or many objects will be active to the last object it added to

---

```
func addTap(_ lbl:UILabel) {
  lbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true 
  lbl.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction)))
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. (I'd upvote, but I don't have enough reputation to) Any idea how to not have to copy paste that "let tap..." line? (I have to do this with like 30 labels)

Comment: for 30 - didn't see the design but consider using a tableView if possible ? or call the above method for every lbl , BTW when you have a duplicated code always think of a function/class/module

Answer (score 0):

You can try using tags like this....

```
func newFrees() -> Void {

    BM1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    BT2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    BTM1.tag = 1
    BTM2.tag = 2
    let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
    BM1.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
    BT2.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
}

    @objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
        print("tap working")
        guard let label = sender.view as? UILabel else { return }
        switch label.tag {
        case 1:
            //DO stuff with label 1
        case 2:
            //Do Stuff with label 2
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```